# Retrieving single firestore doc in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve and display a single doc from a collection when I click on a view link. At the moment I get routed to the view page successfully but unable to display the properties of the doc I want. Here's the code I'm working with

schedule.service.ts

```
getSchedule(id: string) {
  return this.afs
    .collection("schedules")
    .doc(id)
    .ref.get()
    .then(function(doc) {
      doc.data();
      console.log(doc.data()); //i see the data logged on my console correctly
    });
}
```

then in the view.component.ts file

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.scheduleDetail();
}

scheduleDetail() {
  const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
  console.log(id); //I see the doc id correctly

  this.schedule = this.scheduleService.getSchedule(id);
  console.log(this.schedule);//I can't see the correct doc data
}
```

`console.log(this.schedule)` does not log the correct data like `console.log(doc.data())` in the service.ts file does. Instead I see this

> ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}
>   What is the right way of getting the doc data from my service into my component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fix with a correct usage of promise:

```
getSchedule(id: string) {
  return this.afs
    .collection("schedules")
    .doc(id)
    .ref.get()
    .then(function(doc) {
      return doc.data();   // here...
    });
}
```

and

```
scheduleDetail() {
  const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
  console.log(id); 

  this.scheduleService.getSchedule(id).then(data => {
    console.log(data);  // ... and here
  });
}
```

Comment: Some progress made, I see the doc I want logged on the console. But when I set `this.schedule = data` inside then function and try to read a property, I get an error like this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined
    at Object.eval`

Comment: Unbelievable, simply adding `*ngIf="schedule"` to my component.html fixed the error. Thanks.